# showing me all the images instead of showing me the DOTS

Tags: jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
td a { margin: 5px }
.nav { margin: 5px 0 }
#nav a, #s7 strong { margin: 0 5px; padding: 3px 5px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #fc0; text-decoration: none }
#nav a.activeSlide { background: #ea0 }
#nav a:focus { outline: none; }
#output { text-align: left; }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cycle_all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.cycle.defaults.timeout = 6000;
$(function() {
$('#s4').cycle({
        fx:     'scrollHorz',
        speed:  'fast',
        timeout: 0,
        cleartypeNoBg: true,
        pager:  '#nav',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function paginate(idx, el) {
            return '<a class="service' + idx + '" href="#" >&bull;</a>';

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="demos">
   <table cellspacing="20">
    <tr>
    <td>  
        <h1>Pager</h1>
        <div id="s4" class="pics">
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach6.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
            <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach7.jpg" width="200" height="200" />

        </div>

    </td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

after the little reasearch about the cycle plugin , I have made my own little program in which when the user click on the dots it will change the image  but instead of this its showing me all the images . I dont know what I am doing wrong . this is my 1st programm so plz tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: your return is returning a bullet point not an image. Have you tried modifying this?

Comment: but i need bullet point in this so that the user can click on it ....is it wrong ?? please tell me the correct way

Comment: the bullet point is a encased with a link. can you not keep the link but replace &bull; with the image?

Comment: I have created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cBLxP/ of your DHTML.

Comment: @Zword butit is not working as i want it

Comment: @LiamSorsby can u show me a example and my code is not working properly and you can check my code     jsfiddle.net/cBLxP